# How to use strip_tags with second parameter in CodeIgniter?

Tags: html, codeigniter, strip

How to strip HTML tags, but not all tags? For example i want to have `<br>`, `<b>` etc in textareas.

I have this form validation rule:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_desc', 'Opis', 'min_length[3]|max_length[200]|xss_clean|strip_tags');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) with the second argument.

```
$stripped = strip_tags($str, '<b><br>');
```

You could build an array of allowable elements and then join them for the second argument with...

```
$allowedElementsJoined = '<' . implode('><', $allowedElements) . '>';
```

Comment: I just want valid set_rules function, not adding new lines

Comment: @Saibamen Have you tried putting them in the brackets, e.g. `strip_tags[<b><br>]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use

`strip_tags($string, '<b><br>');`

In second parameter you include all the allowed tags.