# How can I keep HTML styling in a php form storing data in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter

so I have a box where a user enters some data "a description" and it stores in MySQL.
However, html tags such as `<img src="">`, `<a href="">`, etc. do not store there in the 'description' field. How can I allow certain HTML codes to be passed through to MySQL?

This is what the description input box looks like:

```
<?=form_textarea(
    'description',
    $Channels->description,
    'class="field" style="width:306px; height: 70px; margin-left:5px;"'
)?>
```

This is where the form gets passed:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
    'description',
    lang('user_edit_channel_description'),
    'trim|required|strip_tags|xss_clean'
);
```

And then posted to MySQL here:

```
$rows['description'] = $this->input->post('description');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use strip_tags with second parameter in CodeIgniter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298944/how-to-use-strip-tags-with-second-parameter-in-codeigniter)

Comment: MayBe that link helps you out. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the form of the `strip_tags` function with the second parameter, which allows you to specify which HTML tags are allowed.  As explained in [this post](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/198402/#933243), you need to create a callback function to call because the two-parameter version of `strip_tags` cannot be directly used in `set_rules(`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to get rid of `strip_tags` from the validation rules, since that removes all HTML tags. Or, ever better, call [the function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) separately using a second parameter to define what tags you want to allow.